# How to concat strings in rows groupby column and index in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    text
0   dog went to the store.    
0   cat is tall.
0   blue is red.
1   red is blue
1   blue is red
```

How do I concat the strings by row and group by index, so that the new df looks like this?:

```
    text
0   dog went to the store. cat is tall. blue is red.  
1   red is blue.blue is red
```

I've tried, but this is doing nothing and returns back the same number of rows, not sure where to go from here:

```
 df[['text']].groupby(df.index)['text'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (just replace `transform` by `agg`):

```
df[['text']].groupby(df.index)['text'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Output:

```
0    dog went to the store.,cat is tall.,blue is red.
1                             red is blue,blue is red
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: you got it first. but same answer as above.

Comment: @RustyShackleford the other user is using a bot to generate the answers